How to check if an outdated package includes backported security fixes from newer version?
I want to host a web server on my Raspberry Pi 1B on my home network, so I want to make sure the software is up to date to minimize the security risk. I was looking into using lighttpd, and I got it running, but I could only get the 1.4.69 version from apt when the latest version is 1.4.76. Looking at the changelogs, there seems to be some vulnerability patches that I would like to have in my installation.
I've checked several sources and they all seem to agree that
you cannot just install a new version from apt, because they manually need to be added to apt from upstream. I could build from source, but it would be nice to avoid that. But then I came across an answer to this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/970267/how-to-upgrade-lighttpd-1-4-33-to-1-4-47-on-ubuntu-14-04 that said that you could check if the security patches are backported to the older version available in apt.
How do I check if the security fixes from the versions between 1.4.69 and 1.4.76 have been added to the 1.4.69 version installed from apt?
Other potentially related information
Linux raspberrypi 6.6.51+rpt-rpi-v6 #1 Raspbian 1:6.6.51-1+rpt3 (2024-10-08) armv6l GNU/Linux

/etc/apt/sources.list:
deb [ arch=armhf ] http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian/ bookworm main contrib non-free rpi

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ apt show lighttpd
Package: lighttpd
Version: 1.4.69-1
Priority: optional
Section: httpd
Maintainer: Debian lighttpd maintainers <team+lighttpd@tracker.debian.org>
Installed-Size: 814 kB
Provides: httpd, httpd-cgi, lighttpd-mod-accesslog, lighttpd-mod-ajp13, lighttpd-mod-auth, lighttpd-mod-authn-file, lighttpd-mod-cgi, lighttpd-mod-dirlisting, lighttpd-mod-extforward, lighttpd-mod-proxy, lighttpd-mod-rrdtool, lighttpd-mod-sockproxy, lighttpd-mod-ssi, lighttpd-mod-status, lighttpd-mod-userdir, lighttpd-mod-vhostdb, lighttpd-mod-wstunnel
Pre-Depends: init-system-helpers (>= 1.54~)
Depends: libc6 (>= 2.36), libcrypt1 (>= 1:4.1.0), libnettle8, libpcre2-8-0 (>= 10.22), libxxhash0 (>= 0.6.5), media-types | mime-support, systemd-sysv | lsb-base
Recommends: spawn-fcgi, perl:any, lighttpd-mod-deflate, lighttpd-mod-openssl
Suggests: openssl, php-cgi, php-fpm (>= 2:7.4), apache2-utils, lighttpd-doc, lighttpd-mod-webdav, lighttpd-modules-dbi, lighttpd-modules-lua
Conflicts: lighttpd-mod-geoip, lighttpd-mod-trigger-b4-dl
Homepage: https://www.lighttpd.net/
Download-Size: 306 kB
APT-Sources: http://raspbian.raspberrypi.com/raspbian bookworm/main armhf Packages
Description: fast webserver with minimal memory footprint
 lighttpd is a small webserver and fast webserver developed with
 security in mind and a lot of features.
 It has support for
   * CGI, FastCGI and SSI
   * virtual hosts
   * URL rewriting
   * authentication (plain files, htpasswd, LDAP)
   * transparent content compression
   * conditional configuration
   * HTTP proxying
 and configuration is straight-forward and easy.


As a general rule, you should look at the package changelog (in /usr/share/doc/${package}/changelog.Debian.gz, so /usr/share/doc/lighttpd/changelog.Debian.gz in this case) — in particular, CVEs are explicitly mentioned in the changelog. For packages that are shipped unchanged compared to Debian, you can also check the relevant security tracker.
In this instance, I only noticed three security-related fixes in the upstream changelogs:

1.4.73 detects and logs HTTP/2 rapid reset attacks
1.4.76 detects and logs HTTP/2 continuation floods, and updates the release mechanism to reduce the risk of xz-style attacks

None of these are relevant to the 1.4.69 package. The two HTTP/2 related changes only detect and log attacks; lighttpd isn’t vulnerable to the attacks. The packaging change is only relevant to upstream release processes and doesn’t change the security situation of existing artifacts. So the fixes haven’t been backported to the 1.4.69 package because they aren’t needed there.
